# Determine if all $n \times n$ matrices such that $AB = BA$ for a fixed $n \times n$ matrix $B$ form a subspace of $M_{nn}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't know how to start this one. Can I show that $A$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication by saying for following:
 If $a, b \in \mathbb R$ and $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices such that $AB = BA$ then $(aA + bB)B = aAB + bBB$

I'm not even sure this is legitimate what I have done so far. Some help starting would be appreciated.

Why in the duplicate question in the accepted answer does @Arturo say that you also need to show that there is at least one matrix such that $AB = BA$? I thought you only have to show closure under addition and scalar multiplication?
As has @Samuel noted below also.

Comment: Thanks @Italy4. I had a look at that post. It's pretty much the same question, below it was answered more succinctly than the others in that other post.

Comment: The reason you need to show that there is at least one such matrix is that the empty set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, but is not a subspace (since it does not have a 0 vector). For example, consider the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $S=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid a^2+b^2<0\}$. You can prove that if $(a,b),(r,s)\in S$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$, theN $(a,b)+(r,s)\in S$ and $t(a,b)\in S$; but this set is **not** a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, because it is not a vector space: it does not contain $(0,0)$ (or anything, for that matter!). You must prove nonemptyness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is great. First, you shouldn't call the two matrices that lie in the subspace $A$ and $B$ because the name $B$ is already taken. If you take two matrices $A_1,A_2$ in this set so that $A_1B = BA_1$ and $A_2B = BA_2$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then

$$ (aA_1 + bA_2)B = aA_1B + bA_2B = aBA_1 + bBA_2 = B(aA_1 + bA_2) $$

which shows that this set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication (and it is clearly non-empty) so this is a vector subspace.

Comment: Thanks @levap. I am starting to get the hang of this technique of substituting (aA + bB) into an expression to prove subspace.

Comment: @Bucephalus: Great! Just be careful not to use a name that's already taken to denote a member of the set (like $B$ in your case, which is reserved for some fixed matrix).

Comment: Yeah, i was actually using C originally, but I just knew I needed help regardless of whether I used C or B, but I definitely can see why, because B  was not necessarily in this set of matrices, it was just being commuted with.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

I think you have the right idea, but you're messing up the notations.

What you have to prove is

- This set (let's denote it $S$ is not empty.
- If $A, A'$ are in $S$ and $a,a'\in\mathbf R$, then $aA+a'A'$ is in $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $N = \{X\in M_{n,n} \mid XA = AX\}$ is a subspace of $M_{n,n}$. This follows from the fact that:

- The identity element of $M_{n,n}$, namely the zero matrix, is part of $N$ since $0A=A0$.
- Given any two matrices $X,Y\in N$ and two scalars $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\alpha X + \beta Y \in N$ because
  $$A(\alpha X + \beta Y) = \alpha A X + \beta A Y = \alpha XA + \beta YA = (\alpha X + \beta Y)A.$$

Your reasoning was on the right track!

Comment: hi @Samuel. Why is it that your first bullet point is added to show subspace. This was mentioned in the other post of this same question also. Is this related to one of the axioms of vector spaces?

Comment: It is meant to show that the subspace is non-empty. Nevertheless, I should have used the zero matrix instead of the identity one (as the operation is not multiplication but addition).

Comment: Oh yeah. Ok then, so $0 + A = A + 0 = A$. Yep, in some examples it seems like these three axioms are the important ones to show as the other ones are inherited from the parent vector space. Cheers @Samuel.